# Eclipse CDT: indexer reports error on automatic duration conversion while compiler is happy

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse CDT (2018-12 (4.10.0)) for a C++ project (cross compiling with gcc 4.9.2).
In the following code the indexer got a problem with **f(std::chrono::seconds(33));**

```cpp
#include <chrono>

void f(std::chrono::milliseconds) {
}

int main() {
    f(std::chrono::seconds(33));
}
```

The diagnostic says

> Invalid arguments
>   Candidates are
>   void f(std::chrono::duration>)

The compiler processes the file without any problem though.

If I create a simple x86_64 project the indexer is happy.

What setting is incorrect in my project? Apparently both compilers can do the job and the indexer, too.

Under C/C++ General->Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.->Providers->CDT GCC Built-In Compiler Settings->Command to get the compiler specs

I use the following command:

```
arm-v7a-linux-gnueabihf-g++ ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -std=c++11 -dD "${INPUTS}"
```

Is there any setting I can change to make the indexer happy?

Comment: Try `std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >( std::chrono::seconds(33));` Generally it is advisable to do type conversion explicitly, this avoids subtle mistakes.

Comment: I do not recommend the use of `duration_cast` when it is not needed.  Rationale:  `duration_cast` truncates values towards 0.  Truncation can be a source of error.  If you find yourself searching for all of your truncations while debugging, it is a lot easier if there's not a lot of exact conversions masquerading as truncating conversions under `duration_cast`.

Comment: Also, I'd like to find the root cause of this issue as this problem might manifest in different shapes and sizes.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. I tested a new project with the indicated code with the same Eclipse version (2018-12) and gcc version (4.9.2), though my gcc isn't a cross-compiler.

Comment: What I don't understand: If I am not mistaken the indexer is not using the compiler for its work, but got its own parser. How can there be any difference in handling type conversions (assuming there are no breaking changes in the stdlib interface)?

Comment: I agree that cross-compiling shouldn't make a difference here. One thing worth checking: if you do F3 (Open Declaration) on top of the `<chrono>`, does Eclipse find the correct header file (the one that ships with your cross compiler)?

Comment: @HighCommander4: Yes, it does find the correct header. It shows an "Open Declaration" dialog where it offers me to got to std::chrono::duration or std::chrono::seconds, but both code locations are in the correct file.

Comment: Ok, my only other lead is perhaps you have a plugin or something messing things up. Could try with a "vanilla" Eclipse package from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-06/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers) with no plugins installed, and see if you have the same problem? (With that setup, you'll likely be using the native host compiler rather than a cross-compiler, so it'll help eliminate that as a possible issue too.)